# row number with random order of other field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘rank’,  pgid, picfile from pages,
(SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
 where pos = 23
order by Rand()
limit 4
```

This selects image filenames from the database and assigns them a row number. Unfortunately, the order by Rand() then randomises these rows, so the images always have the same row number, but the 'rank' field is randomly ordered.

```
rank picfile
3     c.jpg
1     a.jpg
4     b.jpg
2     d.jpg
```

What I want is the 'rank' order always to be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 but the picfile name to be randomly ordered

```
rank picfile
1     a.jpg
2     d.jpg
3     c.jpg
4     b.jpg
```

and the next time the query is run, I want, for example, ....

```
rank picfile
1     b.jpg
2     d.jpg
3     a.jpg
4     c.jpg
```

Hope I've explained it properly!

Many thanks in anticipation
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine has provided the solution:

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 'rank',  r1.* FROM
    (SELECT  pgid, picfile from pages,
             (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS r2
     where pos= 23 
     order by Rand()  limit 5
   ) AS r1
ORDER BY rank
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make the `rownum` portion an outer query:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘rank’, * 
FROM 
    (SELECT pgid, picfile FROM pages, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
        WHERE pos = 23
        ORDER BY Rand()
        LIMIT 4
    )
ORDER BY rank
```

Comment: Thanks Chris - unfortunately, that doesn't work. I get error 1064  ou have an erro in your SQL syntax; check....near '* FROM (SELECT pgid, ....' at line 1